# Add a javascript var and send it with post

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've got this code:

```
$image_action = $_POST['image_action'];   
echo '  
<form action="" method=post onmousedown="rightbutton(event)">
<input type="image"  
            src="image.jpeg"  
            style="cursor:crosshair"  />   
        </form>      '; 

<script type="text/javascript">
function rightbutton(event)
{
    if(event.button==2) {  document.getElementById("click").innerHTML="Last action: Right Click";  }
    else{
        if(event.button==0) {  document.getElementById("click").innerHTML="Last action: Left Click";  }  
        else {
            if(event.button==1) {  document.getElementById("click").innerHTML="Last action: Middle Click";  }
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

Well, what I'm trying to do is get information about which mouse button the user clicked in a new page, so in the new page, I'll do diferent things accordingly. I was trying to do something like this :

```
method = method || "post";
var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", image_action);
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", event);
form.appendChild(hiddenField);
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

But I got the error: `Undefined index: key`

Comment: What's happen if you debug hidden element via console.log() function?

Comment: besides the remark from Samuel, I would also sugest setting the value to event.button value rather than just event, which can't be passed through post variable...

Comment: well, I had "    form.setAttribute("method", method);  " after method = method || "post"; " and there hasn't been any changes :(
I've also changed "        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", event.button);"